# Regex for Kata.StringCalculator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regexp in the StringCalculator kata with that I want to find out if the string contains the definition for the use delimiter or not.

My input string is

```
//[;]\n1;2;3
```

My regexp is

```
//\[(.)\]\\n(.+)
```

My regexp will be parse a that what I expect: http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=//%5C%5B%28.%29%5C%5D%5Cn%28.+%29&env=env_js

In this online tester I see the expected result: http://www.brain4.de/programmierecke/js/tools/regex.php

```
String.match(RegExp) returns: »//[;]\n1;2;3« »;« »1;2;3«
RegExp.exec(String) returns: //[;]\n1;2;3,;,1;2;3
RegExp.test(String) returns: true
String.search(RegExp) returns: 0
```

The following code in JavaScript returns **null** but I don't see why:

```
new RegExp('//\[(.)\]\n(.+)').exec('//[;]\n1;2;3')
```

Comment: See my answer below. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer so that it is removed from the question stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
new RegExp('//\\[(.)\\]\n(.+)').exec('//[;]\n1;2;3')
```

Note that you have to escape the backslash itself in the regex otherwise it matches itself literally (the way it's matching in \n).

Comment: Thanks, your regex is working. But I'm not sure what was wrong. With **\\[** I want to to escape **[** because it's a metacharacter in a regex.

Comment: For that you had to escape the **\** first using **\\**.